# Android: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: on copy to clipboard selected text on long press event

Tags: android

In my app I would like to give copy to clipboard selected text functionality on long press event.foo is a text view 
foo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_string);.
I am using the below code to implement this functionality.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    activateToolbar();
    text = parseSourceCode(text);

    foo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_string);
    foo.setTextSize(mRatio + 14);
    foo.setText(Html.fromHtml(text,imgGetter, null));
    foo.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            String stringYouExtracted = foo.getText().toString();
            int startIndex = foo.getSelectionStart();
            int endIndex = foo.getSelectionEnd();
            stringYouExtracted = stringYouExtracted.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                clipboard.setText(stringYouExtracted);
            } else {
                android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", stringYouExtracted);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I am able to set the text but my code is getting crashed when I press long on the screen to copy the selected text. 
Error I am getting is :

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3704; regionStart=-1; regionLength=0 at 
java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:504) at
java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1333) at 
java.lang.String.subSequence(String.java:1671) –
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `()` here:

```
String stringYouExtracted = foo.getText().toString(); -- add ()
```

Check for instance [toString() from String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString%28%29) - and `subString` is actually [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29):

```
stringYouExtracted = stringYouExtracted.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

***p.s.:*** (as per comment):

```
stringYouExtracted = stringYouExtracted.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
                              getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("text", stringYouExtracted);
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
```

Check example at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html.

***p.p.s.:*** use [`android:textIsSelectable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textIsSelectable) to make text from a `TextView` selectable

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/single_string"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:text="Some text" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.But what about the clipboard settext method.what api should I use instead of this depreciated api.

Comment: Note that  `android.text.ClipboardManager` is deprecated whereas  `android.content.ClipboardManager` is the new API (package changed)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please see my edited code it is getting crashed when handling long press event.

Comment: What exception did you get? Note: `newPlainText` has two `CharSequence`'s as data - so you could omit the `substring` and use `subSequence` instead (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html#subSequence%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: I am getting below error                                                                                               java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3704; regionStart=-1; regionLength=0
            at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:504)
            at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1333)
            at java.lang.String.subSequence(String.java:1671)

Comment: I'd suppose you add a break point in line `stringYouExtracted = stringYouExtracted.substring(startIndex, endIndex);` and check contents of `stringYouExtracted`, `startIndex` and `endIndex`. For some reason the indexes are out of range ...

Comment: As you said I check the content of Extracted string. It is coming proper as expected, but startIndex and endIndex is coming -1

Comment: Did you select any text inside the `EditText` field? From the documentation: `public static final int getSelectionEnd (CharSequence text)` _"Return the offset of the selection edge or cursor, or -1 if there is no selection or cursor. "_ - so I guess there was no text selected. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html#getSelectionEnd%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: Thanks for the inputs,but I need to select text from the textview not from the editbox.Please check my edited code.Is there any way by which I can selected text from the TextView

Comment: Trinimon:Thanks a lot for your help. I added                 android:textIsSelectable="true" inside textview and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
  foo.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            String stringYouExtracted = foo.getText().toString();
            int startIndex = foo.getSelectionStart();
            int endIndex = foo.getSelectionEnd();
            stringYouExtracted = stringYouExtracted.subString(startIndex, endIndex);
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipboard.setText(stringYouExtracted);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

It's toString() not toString, it's a method.

Edit1:
There is 1 more mistake on subString method, the correct way is `substring(startIndex, endIndex);`